# OptaPlanner : 2 dimension problem, check all combinations in one dimension only

Tags: java, algorithm, optaplanner

I'm working on a problem that consist of put item into groups with OptaPlanner.

- Hard score is calculated with constraints. -1 if al least one constraint criteria is not satisfied, 0 otherwise
- Medium score is calculated only if hard = 0, it's an addition of the price of each group
- Soft score is just here to prefer group with more item inside if the calculation of price is disabled

Currently, medium is calculated by HTTP call in an intranet network, so i try to optimize hard score calculation to reduce HTTP call number.

Currently i used this following algorithm and it return the correct result with a lot of my use cases.

```
<scoreDirectorFactory>
 <initializingScoreTrend>ANY</initializingScoreTrend>   
 <easyScoreCalculatorClass>com.project.GroupingScoreCalculator</easyScoreCalculatorClass>
</scoreDirectorFactory>

<constructionHeuristic />
```

Now, i got a case that the best solution is not tested by OptaPlanner with this configuration.
I captured some solutions and drawed them (see following image).

[image: Some solutions]

- S1 is tested and the retained solution by OptaPlanner, but it's not the real optimal solution.
- S2, S3, S4, S5 are tested but not satisfy hard contraint, so medium = 0
- S7, S8 are currently not tested and i don't want them to be tested (i will explain this below)

**Expected :**

1. I want OptaPlanner return me S6 solution instead of S1. I think it's currently normal due to construction heuristic algorithm, but i don't know which algorithm i need to use.
2. For example, S1 & S7 and S2 & S8 are same for me, the number of the group doesn't affect score if items in group are same. If i get both tested, i will have duplicate HTTP call for the same solution. (If i don't have choice, i will try to implement a cache system as mentionned in OptaPlanner documentation)

I'm not an expert of algorithm, i'm learning by practice while building this one.

By reading the documentation, i think Exhaustive Search will check S1 and S6, but will also check S7 and S8. And as i understand, local search and exhaustive search doesn't stop automatically. Is there any way to check all combinations for the Item dimension and stop automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, OptaPlanner runs a Construction Heuristic and a Local Search. By configuring the Construction Heuristic, you disabled the Local Search.
Instead, try limiting the Local Search by adding a termination. You can do this on a global level but also on the local Search level only:

```
<constructionHeuristic/>
<localSearch>
   <termination>
        <stepCountLimit>100</>
   </>
</>
```

There are different forms of termination (see docs), but spentLimit and unimprovedSpentLimit are most common.

An Exhaustive Search will stop automatically. In non-trivial cases it might take a few billion years before it does so, because ES doesn't scale.